# PHP Logic Assistance (Selecting Highest Value in Array / Randomly choosing if they match)

Tags: php, mysqli, logic

I'm creating a Statistical Based 'AI' system for Rock, Paper, Scissors that uses a DB to store what Players most commonly throw next after a specific pattern of throws. They are stored in the database in the way displayed below.

```
ThrowHistory - [[Player Throws],[AI Throws]] (JSON Encoded Array) | Rock | Paper | Scissors
[["Paper","Scissors","Paper"],["Rock","Paper","Rock"]]            |     4|      3|        4
```

Using the information displayed in the DB (as shown above), I need to get the highest value of the Rock, Paper, Scissor fields and return the field name (to show the most common throw). If, like in the example above, the highest value is in two/three fields it needs to choose randomly between them, so in this case it must randomly choose between Rock and Scissors.

The code I currently use is:

```
    $StrQuery = "SELECT Rock, Paper, Scissors FROM tblThrows WHERE ThrowHistory = ?";
    $StrThrowHistory = json_encode($_SESSION["ThrowHistory"]);
    if ($statement = TF_Core::$MySQLi->DB->prepare($StrQuery)) {
        $statement->bind_param('s', $StrThrowHistory);
        $statement->execute();
        $results = $statement->get_result();
        $row = $results->fetch_assoc();

        $LstThrowNumbers = array("Rock" => $row["Rock"], "Paper" => $row["Paper"], "Scissors" => $row["Scissors"]);
    }

    if(count(array_unique($LstThrowNumbers)) != 1){
        return array_search(max($LstThrowNumbers), $LstThrowNumbers);
    }
    else{
        $LstOutcomes = array("Rock", "Paper", "Scissors");
        $IntPredictedThrow = rand(0, 2);
        return $LstOutcomes[$IntPredictedThrow];
    }
```

However, this code does not seem to work (no error just skips to the else) and even if it did it is not a perfect solution as it would randomly pick between all 3 options rather than the two highest values. So I need to figure out a new solution, however that's where I'm out of simple ideas. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new array ordered by number of times a moved has appeared, and use `shuffle` to randomize the order in case of multiple highest matches:

```
//in your case, $row is returned from sql
$row = [
    'rock'=>4,
    'paper'=>3,
    'scissors'=>4
];

//array to hold values index by number of times move has appeared
$temp=[];

foreach($row as $k=>$v)
    $temp[$v][]=$k;

//sort the array, the last element now holds the highest move(s);
ksort($temp);

//get the last element, this is an array with 1,2 or 3 elements
$highest = array_pop($temp);

//shuffle the array, randomizing the order
shuffle($highest);
//grap the last elements in the shuffled array
$chosen = array_pop($highest);

var_dump($chosen); //will randomly show rock or scissors
```

Comment: @ThomasSmyth No problem, glad i could help you